# Expand and collapse table row in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

Below is the example where only expansion is happening, but I want the row to collapse when you click it.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-expandable-table-rows?file=app%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.ts

I want my table to be like this:

[image: table]

Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace
`(click)="expandedElement = row"`

with

`(click)="expandedElement === row? expandedElement = null : expandedElement = row"`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-expandable-table-rows-8ypyfu?file=app%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.html

Comment: Hi @yousef Do you have any idea how to give up and down arrow icon so it should toggle  when I click any row.

Comment: @Priyanka You can add conditional css using `ngClass` or `ngStyle`. Where you already have the condition written above. It should be straightforward.

Comment: <mat-icon>{{ expandedElement ? 'keyboard_arrow_down' : 'keyboard_arrow_up' }}</mat-icon>

This line is working fine but its changing in each row .. it should change for particular row clicked

Comment: <mat-icon>{{expandedElement === row? 'keyboard_arrow_up' : 'keyboard_arrow_down' }}</mat-icon>

Comment: its toggling only once and in all the rows. after that its not changing

Comment: @Priyanka. Share stackblitz

Comment: its working now I used
      <div class="example-element-detail" [@detailExpand]="element== expandedElement ? 'up' : 'down'">
              <mat-icon>{{ report == expandedElement   ?  'keyboard_arrow_up' : 'keyboard_arrow_down' }}</mat-icon>
        </div>

Comment: How to add values under the "Weight" column?

Answer (score 0):

You can add expand property to each row to decide the expand and contract of that row.
Here is the working example on stackblitz : [mat-table-with-row-grouping-and-expandable-rows](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table-with-row-grouping-and-expandable-rows?file=README.md)